# I am getting multiple hydration errors but cannot find the source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, next.js

I am currently attempting to render the 'Swap' page for my DApp made with nextjs and hardhat. Upon navigating to the 'Swap' page I get the error message:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

Along with the following console errors:

```
Error: Invalid curve
    at a (de297ff1-5db1172d27bc5a6f.js:6:84940)
    at new g (de297ff1-5db1172d27bc5a6f.js:15:2181)
    at Object.get [as secp256k1] (de297ff1-5db1172d27bc5a6f.js:15:2373)
etc.
```

```
A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
```

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Minified React error #418 represents the following error:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

Minified React error #423 represents the following error:

```
There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

I am still new to coding however it does not appear to me that there is an obvious problem with my jsx being improperly mounted.

I will attach the GitHub repository bellow. In order to access the 'Swap' page navigate to pages/Swap. I've been trying to solve this error for 24 hours now with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.
https://github.com/BeauC2481/dao