# React context (maybe) causing NextJS production runtime errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**EDIT**: Simplified the code down, but where I'm simplifying is only a guess, so if you need more context, the original details are at the end.

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting a bunch of minified React errors in my NextJS production build, even though I'm not seeing any errors in development (errors [418](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=418), [423](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=423), and [425](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=425)).

**EDIT**: to be clear, everything renders "fine", but because of those errors, it's rendering from the root on the client, which makes the page slow.

After a very painful process, which is probably subject of another SO question on how to debug this stuff, I've managed to narrow it down to one specific commit. Unfortunately, the commit is rather substantial.

Nevertheless, after hacking at it a bit, I think it might be similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74119370/i-am-getting-multiple-hydration-errors-but-cannot-find-the-source), which has a solution of wrapping things in `useEffect`. I *am* already wrapping things in `useEffect`, but I don't have a deep understanding of how the dependency array works there, nor of React context, to which this is all tied. So, I *think* the problem is something with my implementation of context and `useEffect`.

The page topology looks like this:

```
<body>
    //lots of content
    <PurchaseSection>
        <PurchaseCard />
        <PurchaseCard />
        ...
        <StripeForm />
     </PurchaseSection>
</body>
```

The `StripeForm` component is wrapped in an `intersectionObserver`, and once it's scrolled far enough, it hits an API to set up a Stripe `paymentIntent` based on whichever of the `PurchaseCard`s is marked as "primary". That's all constructed as a static page from the CMS using `getStaticProps`, and all works fine.

What I was trying to do is then have it so when a user clicks on one of the `PurchaseCards`, that card becomes "active", both updating its styles, and hitting an API to update the `paymentIntent` with the details of the newly selected `PurchaseCard`. That update will be conducted by the `StripeForm`.

I put some thought into how to do this, and while it probably could have been done just with React state, it seemed like a perfect use for React context.

Can anyone see in the below what I'm doing wrong, either with context, or with the `useEffect`s, that might be causing my undiagnosable minified errors?

I've added what I take to be a fairly standard context wrapper component:

```
 // active-product.js
 import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

 const initialState = { 
    id: null,
    type: '',
    parentId: null
 };
 const ActiveProductContext = createContext(initialState);
 
 function ActiveProductProvider({ children }) {
     const [activeProductState, dispatchActiveProduct] = useReducer((activeProductState, action) => {
        return {
            id: action.payload.id, 
            type: action.payload.type,
            parentId: action.payload.parentId
        }
     }, initialState);
 
     return (
         <ActiveProductContext.Provider value={{ activeProductState, dispatchActiveProduct }}>
             {children}
         </ActiveProductContext.Provider>
     );
 }
 
 function useActiveProduct() {
     return useContext(ActiveProductContext);
 }
 
 export { ActiveProductProvider, useActiveProduct }
```

That gets used as a wrapper around the whole `PurchaseSection`:

```
export default function LandingPageSection({details}) {

    switch(details.__typename) {
        ...
        case 'PurchaseSectionRecord':
            return (
                <ActiveProductProvider>
                    <PurchaseSection products={details.products} />
                </ActiveProductProvider>
            )
        ...
    }
}
```

### **Redacted version**

Then it gets used (currently) in two places: the `PurchaseSection` component itself, and `PurchaseCard`s. (Ultimately it will get used in the `StripeForm` as well, but ... one step at a time).

```
const PurchaseSection = ({products}) => {
  ...

  const { activeProductState } = useActiveProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
    // we only enter this the first time the section intersects
    if (!isPurchaseSectionRef) {
        // do stripe stuff


        // this `activeProductState` should be set from the 
        // default `PurchaseCard` we got from the CMS, and I
        // guess should be "static" from the Next build.
        fetch('api/create-payment-intent', {
          method: 'POST',
          header: { 'Content-Type': 'applcation/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            productId: activeProductState.id,
            productType: activeProductState.type,
            parentId: activeProductState.parentId
          })
        })
        ...
  }, [purchaseSectionRefValue]);

  return (  
    <section ref={purchaseSectionRef}>
      ...
  )
}
```

And finally, in the `PurchaseCard`:

```
const PurchaseCard = ({details}) => {
    ...
    const { activeProductState, dispatchActiveProduct } = useActiveProduct();
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        // if activeProductState.id isn't set, then we haven't gotten
        // gotten to the card which is chosen by default in the CMS,
        // whence "primary" is set
        if (! activeProductState.id && primary) {
            dispatchActiveProduct({payload: {
                id: product.id,
                type: product.__typename,
                parentId: id
            }});
            setIsSelected(true);
        } else if (activeProductState.id === product.id) {
            setIsSelected(true);
        } else {
            setIsSelected(false);
        }
    }, [activeProductState, setIsSelected]);


    const handleClick = () => {
        // if someone clicks on one of the cards, we update the
        // React context
        dispatchActiveProduct({payload: {
            id: product.id,
            type: product.__typename,
            parentId: id
        }});
    }
    ...

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
           ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

### **Original Version**

Then it gets used (currently) in two places: the `PurchaseSection` component itself, and `PurchaseCard`s. (Ultimately it will get used in the `StripeForm` as well, but ... one step at a time).

```
const PurchaseSection = ({products}) => {
  const purchaseSectionRef = useRef();
  const purchaseSectionRefValue = showOnScreen(purchaseSectionRef); // wrapper for IntersctionObserver
  const [ isPurchaseSectionRef, setIsPurchaseSectionRef ] = useState(false);

  const [ stripePromise, setStripePromise ] = useState(null);
  const [ clientSecret, setClientSecret ] = useState('');

  const { activeProductState } = useActiveProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if we've ever seen the section before, don't change anything, so we don't rerender
    if (!isPurchaseSectionRef) {
      setIsPurchaseSectionRef(purchaseSectionRefValue);

      // only do Stripe interactions if we've intersected
      if (purchaseSectionRefValue) {
        fetch('api/keys', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(async (data) => {
            const getStripe = (await import('../lib/get-stripejs')).default;
            setStripePromise(getStripe(data.publishableKey));
        })

        fetch('api/create-payment-intent', {
          method: 'POST',
          header: { 'Content-Type': 'applcation/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            productId: activeProductState.id,
            productType: activeProductState.type,
            parentId: activeProductState.parentId
          })
        })
        .then(async (res) => {
          const { clientSecret } = await res.json();
          setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        })
      }
    }
  }, [purchaseSectionRefValue]);

  return (  
    <section ref={purchaseSectionRef}>
      <div>
        {products.map((item) => <PurchaseCard key={item.id} details={item} />)}
      </div>
      ...
    </section>
  )
}
```

And finally, in the `PurchaseCard`:

```
const PurchaseCard = ({details}) => {
    const {
        discountAmount = 0,
        discountAmountPct = null,
        discountEndDate = null,
        primary = false,
        id = '',
        product
    } = details;

    const { activeProductState, dispatchActiveProduct } = useActiveProduct();
    const [ isSelected, setIsSelected ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // if activeProductState.id isn't set, then we haven't gotten
        // gotten to the card which is chosen by default in the CMS,
        // whence "primary" is set
        if (! activeProductState.id && primary) {
            dispatchActiveProduct({payload: {
                id: product.id,
                type: product.__typename,
                parentId: id
            }});
            setIsSelected(true);
        } else if (activeProductState.id === product.id) {
            setIsSelected(true);
        } else {
            setIsSelected(false);
        }
    }, [activeProductState, setIsSelected]);


    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatchActiveProduct({payload: {
            id: product.id,
            type: product.__typename,
            parentId: id
        }});
    }
    ...

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            { product?.name ? <h3>{product.name}</h3> : null }
            { eventDate ? <p>{eventDate}</p> : null }
            { product?.location && <DatoContent content={product.location} /> }
            { displayPrice() }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<PurchaseCard key={item.id} details={item} />)}
```

```
const PurchaseCard = ({details}) => {}
```

Try using props and then access details with props.details,
like this :

```
const PurchaseCard = (props) => {
const {
        discountAmount = 0,
        discountAmountPct = null,
        discountEndDate = null,
        primary = false,
        id = '',
        product
    } = props.details;
}
```

Beside that, try to remove code and see when it render successfully.

Too much code for me to understands what cause the error..

Comment: Yeah. I appreciate it's a lot of code. Problem is, it always renders successfully. it's just that it renders client side from the root in production, so it's _slow_. And since it doesn't happen in dev, it's hard to quickly iterate, removing little bits at a time. I'll see if I can clean it up.